How to detect a lost Prius key fob inside a house
I lost a keychain with a 2012 Toyota Prius key fob together with another key that has sentimental value attached to it. It’s most likely lost somewhere in the house, but with fairly extensive searching, I haven’t been able to find it. The keychain didn’t have any aftermarket “key finder” on it. I have another key fob that I’ve been using for the same car.
Is there any way to find the original key fob by proximity using a radio device? If so, what equipment would I need and how would I set it up to do this?
I saw the similar Is it possible to use radio to find a lost car key fob? but there was no definitive answer, just speculation about whether the key fob acts as a transmitter or a receiver. And that question was also about a Kia. Specific knowledge about how a 2012 Prius key fob communicates with the car would be useful.
